# Android error, Unforunately, Has Launcher stopped

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile

I'm working on an Android app that makes geolocalization using Google Maps API, and all is well for now except that when I install my application (to test) on some mobile devices an error is displayed (and my app runs well).
Error ==> Unforunately, Has Launcher stopped. Please, are there anyone who can explain this to me !!
Thank you in advance and good day.

Comment: where your code? also post logcat pls :)

Comment: Without the logcat and the relevant code it would be *almost impossible* to help you. Please add them.